# Can we keep change-tracking on a replicated table going after changing the distribution database?

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication, change-data-capture

We have an MSSQL replicated table which has change-tracking set up on the subscribed table.
The change tracking is used to send changes into Snowflake.
However - now we need to reconfigure replication (change the distribution DB).
This will snapshot load that change-tracking table again.
Is there a way to keep the change tracking going without resending all the table rows into Snowflake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Just don't initialize the subscriber with a snapshot.  Make sure no changes occur to the publisher while you're recreating the replication topology with the new distributor, and your subscriber should in the correct state to start replication, and you can use Manual initialization for the subscriber.

> **[Initializing a subscription with an alternative method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/initialize-a-transactional-subscription-without-a-snapshot?view=sql-server-ver16#initializing-a-subscription-with-an-alternative-method)**
>
> It is possible to initialize a subscription using any method that
> allows you to copy the publication database schema and data to the
> Subscriber, such as Integration Services. When you use an alternative
> method to initialize the Subscriber, replication support objects are
> copied to the Subscriber.
>
> Unlike initializing with a backup, you or your application must ensure
> the data and schema are properly synchronized at the time you add the
> subscription. If, for example, there is activity on the Publisher
> between the time data and schema are copied to the Subscriber and the
> time at which the subscription is added, changes resulting from this
> activity might not be replicated to the Subscriber.
>
> To initialize a subscription with an alternative method, see
> [Initialize a Subscription Manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/initialize-a-subscription-manually?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Yes, the table will be in active use, and we don't want to loose those changes.

Comment: I am upvoting the answer. It didn't resolve my issue, but it could have.